# How do I hide an application by clicking the dock icon?

Tags: applications, dock

Is it possible to configure the dock in such a way that a non-visible application becomes visible when the dock icon is clicked the first time and becomes invisible again when the dock icon is clicked a second time? I'm aware that with a long press and choosing Hide I can achieve what I want with just one click.

Comment: Opt/click on switch to another app will hide the one your backgrounding.

Comment: Great. That is the answer.

Comment: Let me throw that into the answer space - hopefully this time without autocorrect ruining my grammar ;))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opt/click on switching to another app will hide the one you're backgrounding.

You can also do this by Opt/clicking any visible window of your new app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DockAltTab or Dock Exposé for this. Plus then you also get window previews when hovering over dock icons. (disclaimer: am the developer)